# [cmake]how to include and link system libraries on windows using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, nmake

this's my cpp code:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>

int main(char** args, int size)
{
    printf("aaaaa\n");
    return 1;
}
```

this's my **CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(PROJECT_ROOT_PATH "./")
add_executable(app ${PROJECT_ROOT_PATH}/app.c)
```

my steps running command is following:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ./
nmake
```

when I run nmake, there are many errors like this:

```
D:\Program_Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cstdio(36): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using' [E:\cmake-test\app.vcxproj]
D:\Program_Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cstdio(36): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'using' [E:\cmake-test\app.vcxproj]
```

if keep a empty function there:

```
#pragma once

int main(char** args, int size)
{
    return 1;
}
```

nmake would works righ and output an executable file:**app.exe**

is the problem that I didn't specify includes and libraries of windows SDK?
if so, how can I configurate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File `cstdio` might contain C++ specific stuff. C++ is a superset of a subset of C, so not every C++ code is valid C.

CMake compiles your `.c` file as C, thus syntax errors.

In your case the source of the error is C++ `using` statements that do not exist in C programming language.

To fix the problem either:

- `#include <stdio.h>` (and compile as C as it was)

or

- rename the file to `.cpp` (so it would be compiled as C++)